# order_by from a query makes unrelated query fail

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I'm facing a problem where I cannot use `order_by` in one of my MYSQL query as it makes another one not working. What I do not understand is that **both queries are unrelated and changing the first one shouldn't affect the second one**.
Can you see why `order_by` is affecting `list_all_resorts`?

I've added some comments (//) to the intesresting parts.

```
$shift_level = $this->shift_previous_day($list_all_resorts, 'level');

protected function shift_previous_day($list_all_resorts, $type) {
    foreach ($list_all_resorts->result() as $list_all_resorts_Array){
        $shift_DB = $this->shift_previous_day_DB($list_all_resorts_Array->id_resort, $type);
    }
    echo $shift_previous_day_DB;
} 
    
protected function shift_previous_day_DB($id_resort, $type){
    $this->db->trans_start();
    $this->db->set($type.'_d134', $type.'_d133', FALSE);
    $this->db->set($type.'_d1', $type.'_d0', FALSE);
    $this->db->set($type.'_d0', '0', FALSE);
    $this->db->where('id_resort', $id_resort);
    $this->db->update('game_resort_'.$type); 
    $this->db->order_by('season', 'DESC');  // If I remove this line there is no error thrown
    $this->db->limit('1'); 
    $this->db->trans_complete();
    if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE){
        return log_message();
    }
    else {
        $result = 'all OK';
        return $result;
    }  
}

$add_cash_to_history = $this->add_todays_stat_to_history('cash'); 
 
//This is where list_all_resorts will fail. Before that it works fine
protected function add_todays_stat_to_history($data_type) {
    $info_message = '';
    $list_all_resorts = $this->list_all_resorts();  // The is where list_all_resorts is called
    foreach ($list_all_resorts->result() as $row_list_all_resorts){
        //do some stuff
    }
    return $info_message;
}
    
protected function list_all_resorts(){  
    $this->db->select('id_resort'); // This is where the error points to
    $this->db->from('game_resorts');
    return $this->db->get();
}
```

The error I get is:

> A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1054 Unknown column 'season'
>
> in 'order clause' SELECT `game_resorts`.`id_resort` FROM
>
> `game_resorts` ORDER BY `season` DESC LIMIT 1

Update:

```
describe game_resorts:
id_resort   int(11) NO  PRI     auto_increment  
resort_name varchar(45) NO              
resort_country  varchar(45) YES             
resort_description  varchar(256)    YES             
id_player   int(11) YES MUL 

describe `game_resort_cash`:
id  int(11) NO  PRI         
id_resort   int(11) NO  MUL         
season  int(3)  NO      1       
cash_d0 int(11) YES             
cash_d1 int(11) YES                         
cash_d134   int(11) YES
```

Comment: From your error message MySQL thinks that column season does not exist in the game_resorts table. Are you sure the column season exists in the game_resorts table? Double checked the spelling on both?

Comment: Could you provide the output of `describe game_resorts;` please?

Comment: but `list_all_resorts` doesn't deal with table `'game_resort_'.$type`, which is something like `'game_resort_cash'`. Only `'game_resort_cash'` contains `season`. `game_resorts` does NOT contain `season` and I never request `season` from that table. or do I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that `$this->db` is the same object in both function calls, so let's look at the sequence of calls it receives:

```
//From shift_previous_day_DB
$this->db->trans_start();
$this->db->set($type.'_d134', $type.'_d133', FALSE);
$this->db->set($type.'_d1', $type.'_d0', FALSE);
$this->db->set($type.'_d0', '0', FALSE);
$this->db->where('id_resort', $id_resort);
$this->db->update('game_resort_'.$type); 
$this->db->order_by('season', 'DESC');
$this->db->limit('1'); 
$this->db->trans_complete();
//From list_all_resorts
$this->db->select('id_resort');
$this->db->from('game_resorts');
$this->db->get();
```

There are methods that just set up the `db` object for when the next query is executed, and methods that execute the query and reset the object. [`update`](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html#update) and `get` are of the second group, while `set`, `where`, `order_by`, `limit`, `select`, and `from` are of the first. `trans_start` and `trans_complete` work independently of them.

As the calls to `order_by` and `limit` are after the call to `update`, they affect the next statement, that is, the `get`. You can see that in the error message: not only there's a `ORDER BY season DESC`, but also a `LIMIT 1` in the generated statement.

To fix this, you should put `order_by` and `limit` before `update`:

```
$this->db->trans_start();
$this->db->set($type.'_d134', $type.'_d133', FALSE);
$this->db->set($type.'_d1', $type.'_d0', FALSE);
$this->db->set($type.'_d0', '0', FALSE);
$this->db->where('id_resort', $id_resort);
$this->db->order_by('season', 'DESC');
$this->db->limit('1'); 
$this->db->update('game_resort_'.$type); 
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

Comment: great, that worked! I suspected something like that but I thought the `trans_complete` would reset everything

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are saying SELECT game_resorts.id_resort which would be the id_resort col from the game_resorts table. You are not telling it to look for all cols but specific ones. If you don't want a select all do `SELECT game_resorts.id_resort, game_resorts.season`... in other words: `$this->db->select('id_resort');` Should also call the season column. Update that guy.

Comment: `season` is NOT in `game_resorts` and I do not select it in this query. At least I don't think so... ?

Answer (score 0):

Your query:

```
SELECT game_resorts.id_resort FROM game_resorts ORDER BY season DESC LIMIT 1
```

In this query Mysql not found season column into the game_resorts table. So if you want to do sorting using season then you need to left join with both tables. Because season column found into the game_resort_cash table.

Here is the left join query:

```
select t1.*,t2.* from game_resorts t1
left join game_resort_cash t2
on(t1.id_resort=t2.id_resort) order by t2.season desc limit 1
```

Run this query into your Mysql databse I hope it will be working for you.
Thanks.